# Where is the mistake in my proof?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I tried to prove

$$ \sin(x + iy) = \sin x \cosh y + i \cos x \sinh y$$

but instead I proved $ \sin(x - iy) = \sin x \cosh y + i \cos x \sinh y$.

> Please could someone check my proof and tell me where my mistake is?

$$ 
\begin{align}
\sin x \cosh y + i\cos x \sinh y &= \sin x {e^{-y}+e^y\over 2} + \cos x {e^{y}-e^{-y}\over 2}\\
&= \sin x {e^{-y{i\over i}}+e^{y{i\over i}}\over 2} + \cos x {e^{y{i\over i}}-e^{-y{i\over i}}\over 2}\\\\
&=\sin x \cos {y\over i} + i \cos x \sin {y\over i}\\
&=\sin x \cos {-iy} + i \cos x \sin {-iy}\\
&=\sin(x-iy)
\end{align}
$$

where the last equality follows from $\sin(x-y) = \sin x \cos y - \sin y \cos x$.

Comment: A simpler approach would be to expand the left hand side using the sum of angles formula for the sine function and then note the relationships between the trig functions and hyperbolic functions as can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function

Comment: Where did your $i$ in the first line dissapear?

Comment: @MrYouMath: that $i$ was reincarnated in the third line. The real mistake is dropping the $i$ in the penultimate line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing a very good job keeping track if your $i's$

$\sin x \cosh y + i\cos x \sinh y = \sin x {e^{-y}+e^y\over 2} + i\cos x {e^{y}-e^{-y}\over 2}$

$\sin x {e^{-y{i\over i}}+e^{y{i\over i}}\over 2} + i\cos x {e^{y{i\over i}}-e^{-y{i\over i}}\over 2}$

$\sin y = \frac {e^{iy} - e^{-iy}}{2i}$  so we need to get an $i$ in the denominator on the right-hand term.

$\sin x {e^{-i{y\over i}}+e^{i{y\over i}}\over 2} -\cos x {e^{i{y\over i}}-e^{-i{y\over i}}\over 2i}$

$\sin x \cos \frac yi -\cos x \sin \frac yi$

$\sin x \cos -iy -\cos x \sin -iy$

Remember: $\sin -x = -\sin x, \cos -x = \cos x$

$\sin x \cos iy +\cos x \sin iy\\
\sin (x+iy)$

Comment: Right, thanks man. I had misremembered the definition of $\cosh$ and $\sinh$.

Comment: You dropped the $i$ in the first line, which caused it to come back in the 3rd, when it should have gone away.  And you swept it under the carpet in the 5th line.  And in the 3rd line when it came back, you have the an incorrect sign.

Answer (score 1):

$
\sin(x + iy) = \sin(x) \cos(iy) + \cos(x) \sin(iy) \\
             = \sin(x) \cosh(y) + i \cos(x) \sinh(y) [\because sinh(a) = -i sin(ia), cosh(a) = cos(ia)] \\
$

Also
$
e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \sin(x) \ [\text{ Euler identity}] \\
e^{i(ix)} = \cos(ix) + i \sin(ix) \\
e^{i(-ix)} = \cos(ix) - i \sin(ix) \\ 
e^{i(ix)} + e^{-i(ix)} = 2\cos(ix) \\
e^{-x} + e^{x} = 2\cos(ix) \ [\because i^2 = -1] \\
\frac{e^{-x} + e^{x}}{2} = \cos(ix) \\
cosh(x) = \cos(ix)
$

I will leave the proof of 
$\sinh(x) = -i \sin(ia)$ for you to work